# how to not require certain gems/lines of code in production that I need in development

Tags: ruby, environment-variables, development-environment, ruby-dotenv

**I am not writing in Rails.  It is just ruby.**

But I have a dev environment that has it's own development group in the Gemfile.

But I don't use them in production on Iron.io.

In particular, I use "log_buddy" and have lots of `d {var}` statements throughout.

And I use `pry` which has a `require pry` and `require-debug` statement.

These statements create errors in the case of `pry` and duplicate logging in the case of `log_buddy` when the code runs in production.

How do I make a distinction between the two environments?

I have read about `dotenv` and some other gem, but didn't quite understand how it would work in my scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just `yes`/`no` scenario for dev, `dotenv` family is an overkill. I would go with surrounding dev requirements with:

```
if ENV['DEV']
  require 'pry'
  ...
end
```

and then run development scenarios as:

```
DEV=true bundle exec ...
```

Since `DEV` env variable is not defined on your prod server, nothing will be included there.

Init for `log_buddy` might look like:

```
LogBuddy.init(ENV['DEV'] ? {:logger => Logger.new('my_log.log')} : nil)
```

Comment: Thanks, what does the Init do?  I would like it if there's no DEV environment to pass the following: `LogBuddy.init :disabled => true`

Comment: would I run the web app this way: `DEV = true bundle exec shotgun -o 0.0.0.0 web....rb` (everything from `bundle` on is how I run the app currently in dev mode.

Answer (score 1):

Not using Rails does not prevent you from using [Bundler groups](http://bundler.io/v1.9/groups.html):

```
# These gems are in the :default group
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'sinatra'

gem 'wirble', :group => :development

group :test do
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'rspec'
end

group :test, :development do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

gem 'cucumber', :group => [:cucumber, :test]
```

Then you have to get the environment name in any way you deem reasonable:

```
bundler_env = whatever # could be ENV['ENVIRONMENT'], for instance
bundler_env ||= :production # Specify a fallback if none specified
```

And once you're done, require the gems:

```
Bundler.require(:default, bundler_env)
```

Comment: how would this take care of lines of code that rely on the gems, like log_buddy's `d`?  If I could set the environment variable for log_buddy it could stop output

Comment: *When you occasionally want to disable LogBuddy (but you don't want to have to remove all your debug statements), you can pass the :disabled option into init's options hash* ([ref](https://github.com/relevance/log_buddy))

Comment: And you shouldn't actually have any debug statements in your code except for `debug`-level logging. That's why `rubocop` complains about any `binding.pry` it sees.

Comment: how do I pas the disabled option when it is in production?  Thanks.k

Comment: @Angela example of setting encironment name is right above. Use an `if` on that.

Comment: So 'if bundler_env == develop then' and so as long as I specify bundler env when running that does it?  And is it by saying 'env = true bundler exec shotgun -o .....'?

Comment: @Angela `bunlder` only governs which gems to require, any environment-specific statements are still up to you. The comment above suggests launching via `ENVIRONMENT=test bundle exec whatever ...`, that would make the value `"test"` available in `ENV['ENVIRONMENT']`, so you can make any choices. Rails also uses the environment name to guess which initializer file to load, you could do that too.

Comment: okay so since production would not have an  ENVIRONMENT = test then I can put the logic in my app....I think I get it now, thanks.

Comment: I tried to pass the ENVIRONMENT variabel per above and it gives me an error:  `site git:(master) ✗ ENVIRONMENT = test bundle exec shotgun -o 0.0.0.0 web_post.rb
zsh: command not found: ENVIRONMENT`

Comment: @Angela no spaces near the first =.

Comment: is `Bundler.require(:default, bundler_env)` what I what put in the actual ruby files instead of the list of require 'gem'?